# vscode-devcontainer for rails v4.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, vscode-devcontainer

I'm working on reviving an old project written in rails `v4.1.0` (and ruby `v2.1.9`) dev environment.
I would like to set up a `vscode-devcontainer` so future developers can start developing immediately regardless of their machine OS.

Currently, I'm unable to find a suitable base `vscode-devcontainer`. The min ruby version available is 2.6 which is too high for this project.

Comment: You can create your own `Dockerfile` for your contianer.

Comment: @ikhvjs Can you please provide a working example of this `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Follow this [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/create-dev-container#_dockerfile) from the doc.